# what is the meaning of cvWriteFrame return value?

Tags: c, opencv

I am writing a video capture application and I need to check to make sure that frames are actually being written to file in a timely manner (sometimes this doesn't happen). I see from openCV's [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/videoio/doc/reading_and_writing_video.html#int%20cvWriteFrame(CvVideoWriter*%20writer,%20const%20IplImage*%20image)) that the C api call to `cvWriteFrame` returns an `int`. Will this confirm whether or not the frame got written? I see that the Python and C++ versions of this call don't return anything. No error checking here? Why not?

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use the depreciated

C API: cvWriteFrame

You can use the c++ API: [VideoWriter::write](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/videoio/doc/reading_and_writing_video.html?highlight=cvwriteframe#videowriter-write) or [imwrite](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imwrite#imwrite) 
which will return a bool value that says the success or failure of the write operation!

Comment: This is good news, but the documentation says that VideoWriter::write returns a void, not a boolean. Am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: May i know what doc you are referring?

Comment: The one I link to in the question: http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/videoio/doc/reading_and_writing_video.html

Comment: sort of. My goal is to separate the read and write phases of an openCV based video capture application. My strategy now is to make a lockfree queue object (based on boost::lockfree::spsc_queue) and have the read and write thread read and write to the queue asynchronously. I've not quite got it working yet, but this way I can monitor exactly which frames are written by hand.